# Hyperlink to a cell on another sheet in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

I am working on Excel report in which I need to pass a link which can take me to a cell referenced.

In below example, I have two sheets on same workbook. Now if I click on cell "A1" on Sheet:1, then it should take me to cell "E1" on Sheet:2.

I know by paste special I can pass hyperlink, but tricky part is data on Sheet:2 is dynamic so I can't go that route.
After looking on Google, I have found out multiple things, so I clubbed them together but it is throwing error **"Reference is not valid"**.

Here is the formula that I've used on cell "A1" on Sheet:1:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Sample.xlsx]Sheet:2!(ADDRESS(MATCH(""ABC"",BEFORE,0),MATCH(""ABC"",BEFORE,0),1))","ABC")
```

Here **BEFORE** is a name range that covers A1 to E1.

### Sheet:1

```
    a      b      c      d      e

1.  abc
```

### Sheet:2

```
    a      b      c      d      e

1.  x      x      x      x     abc
```

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: try to remove double quotes: `""ABC""` --> `"ABC"`. And do you really have sheet `Sheet:2` or correct would be `Sheet2`?

Comment: @simoco, if I remove that double quotes, then formula throws an error.

Comment: do you really have sheet `Sheet:2` or correct would be `Sheet2`?

Comment: btw, you can't do it like this: `"Sheet2!(ADDRESS..."`

Comment: @simoco, thanks for the response, I do have name on sheet2, I've just used Sheet:2 for reference. And this is what I got so far, I don't know other way for my requirement.

Comment: as I see, @TimWilliams has just given you the answer:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=HYPERLINK("[Sample.xlsx]'Sheet2'!" & ADDRESS(1,MATCH("abc",BEFORE,0)),"ABC")
```

If your sheet name might have spaces then make sure to add the single quotes around the name.

Comment: awesome, your formula works like a charm. Thanks a lot.